# define width as percentage android

Tags: android

I need help you .I dont know why this code dont run correctly.I want first textview and edittext have 50% space and second textview and edittext have 50% other while it only display  a empty layout.
please help me thanks

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    >
<TextView
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_weight="0.10"
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:id="@+id/lytner_card_question_text"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:textSize="20dp"
   />
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/myparentScrollview"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lytner_card_question_text"

            >

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lytner_card_question_etext"
    android:minHeight="100dp"    
    />

</ScrollView>
<TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="0.10"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:id="@+id/lytner_card_answer_text"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/myparentScrollview"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"

  />
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/myparentScrollview1"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lytner_card_answer_text"

       >
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lytner_card_answer_etext"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
   />
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use fill parent in width and then use weigth attributes

Comment: Use weight attribs on all of your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in adding weight sum to a Relative Layout. It only works for Linear Layout. Change your Relative Layout to a Linear Layout and then try again.

Answer (score 3):

The following code gives you two LinearLayouts as containers, each with height half of the screen:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/container1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Relative** layout **weight** does not work , change your layout to **linear** then try weight.